# How do I determine which py file (and which class within that py file) called another py file?

Tags: python, module

I have a number of py files (and classes within those py files) that are calling  another py file. Let's call the first py files A, B, C, and the py file that they're calling Z. I'd like to run code in Z based on whether A, B, or C called that file. Sometimes, I call A from B, and Z from A in a chain. I'd like to run code in Z based on the last py file that called it.

Here is an example:

```
A.py

import Z

class A1:
    def __init__(self):
        Z.Z1()

B.py
import Z

class B1:
    def __init__(self):
        Z.Z1()

C.py
Import Z
Import A

class C1:
    def __init__(self):
        Z.Z1()
    def callA(self):
        A.A1()

Z.py

if [the name of the method which called Z is A1 init]:
    x = some_abstract_class

if [the name of the method which called Z is B1 init]:
   x = some_other_abstract_class

class Z1(x):
   do_something...
```

In the case of the callA function, I'd still like to know that A1 called Z last.
Is there something to replace the square brackets with in order to get this to work? I was hoping that this would be something as simple as doing if **name** = "A1",  but sadly I don't see this to be the case.

Thank you, and I hope that this was sufficiently clear. Although I've benefited tremendously from Stackoverflow, this is the first time I contribute with a question, hope I didn't completely botch it.

Comment: Hi, I feel like you have an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/768352). You seem to try to solve a problem in a specific way which doesn't work, but it's hard to tell what you actually want to achive. Maybe try to explain what the classes and syntax is supposed to do.

Comment: You can use `inspect` module but I think you're implementing an anti-pattern/code smell. The calling modules should be the ones determining which class/abstract base class it should be using, not the called module.

Comment: I was using tkinter and was trying to load one of two different menus into a page, based on which other page called that page. The pages were structured as classes in OOP style, and the menus were loaded as superclasses. I finally found a different solution to my problem, by a). entering both menus as superclasses into the page; b) requesting a new variable when calling that page, which would allow me to figure out where the page was called from c) calling the init function on one of the superclasses based on where the page was called from. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: I'll try to make my question clearer next time.